"splice" two pipes together?
I would like to launch a process, provide some initial input to it, and then have it "take over" stdin and stdout as though I had execve'd it. While the question is language-independent, here's some python code to explain:
import os
import sys
import subprocess
pid = os.getpid()

def printer():
    print(f"[Printer-{pid}] Startup!")
    for line in sys.stdin:
        print(f"[Printer-{pid}] {line.strip()}")

def launcher():
    try:
        print(f"\t[Launcher-{pid}] Sending initial message.")
        # launches the "printer()" function in another process.
        child = subprocess.Popen(
                (sys.executable, __file__, "printer"),
                stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                universal_newlines=True,
                bufsize=1
        )
        child.stdin.write("Initial setup message!\n")
        print(f"\t[Launcher-{pid}] Turning over control.")
        for line in sys.stdin:
            child.stdin.write(line)
    finally:
        child.kill()
        child.communicate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'printer':
        printer()
    else:
        launcher()

When run (without args), this produces:
    [Launcher-24132] Sending initial message.
    [Launcher-24132] Turning over control.
[Printer-29572] Startup!
[Printer-29572] Initial setup message!
message from stdin
[Printer-29572] message from stdin

If I didn't want the "Initial setup message!\n" bit, I could simply do any language's equivalent of:
def launcher_alternate():
    subprocess.Popen((sys.executable, __file__, "printer"))
    sys.exit(0)

And the child process will inherit the standard streams from its parent. (Might get a bit complicated running in a shell, since the shell will be waiting on its direct child not the grandchild, but the pipes should still be valid. Or we could wait on the child instead of exiting.)
With the "initial setup" message, there's a number of problems:

The parent process needs to stay around to forward messages.
We're doubling the kernel overhead of passing data around in pipes.
We need to make assumptions about how we want our streams to buffer.

It seems like the thing I want is some sort of "duct-tape [input pipe] into [output pipe]". It seems like the reverse operation of pipe where instead of creating a linked pair of fd's, we're destroying both by joining them. Does that exist on Linux/Windows, and if it doesn't, why not?
# DOES NOT EXIST (I think.)
os.splice(sys.stdin, child.stdin)

Again, I'm not looking for python code to do the forwarding, I'm looking for an OS-level answer or an explanation (if one exists) of why there isn't such a feature. I referenced some things that are particular to Linux's unnamed pipes, but if named pipes or Windows has an equivalent of this, that would be a good answer as well.

(This feels like it should have a dupe for it, but searching I couldn't find anything. Apologies if I missed anything. Additionally, feel free to change the tags/edit as you see fit, I don't feel like 'pipe' is the most fitting tag but I wasn't sure what would be best.)

I don't think there's a way to do this. You can't change what the child process's stdin is connected to. It's either connected to the pipe or it inherits the parent's stdin, it can't change on the fly.

If you were doing this in a shell script, you could write (echo "Initial setup message"; cat) | program. cat then takes the place of your program, copying from its stdin to the pipe. But there's no way to get rid of that intermediary.

Checkout expect  - programmed dialogue with interactive programs (Wiki) (tcl-lang.org): spawn [args] program [args] creates a new process running program args. Its stdin, stdout and stderr are connected to Expect, so that they may be read and written by other Expect commands. The connection is broken by close or if the process itself closes any of the file identifiers.
